# Why can't I reasign the "Undo" function as ctrl+y instead of ctrl+shift+z. Why can't I remove the default "yank" command

Tags: rstudio

I NEED the ctrl+y to be redo. I've tried replacing the "redo" command from ctrl+shift+z to ctrl+y, but no matter what it will always do a "paste yank text" when I hit ctrl+y.

If you don't believe my, try to recreate this error for yourself

To add on top of that, yank (ctrl+y) doesn't even appear on the keyboard shortcuts list. It's frustrating and always interferes with my work. There's no reason to have yank when cut and paste already exist. I just need normal undo/redo shortcut behavior just like it is in literally everything else, and the "yank" feature to be permanently gone from my keyboard shortcuts. Either will be a lifesaver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I concur... There's supposed to be a filed bug report for that...

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208103438-Redo-pastes

In the meantime, CTRL-SHIFT-Y works fine, although it's probably not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 31):

R-Studio version 1.2.5001. Now you can.

By default, Redo is now linked to `CTRL+Y`. However, it still doesn't work, as it (still by default) conflicts with `paste Yank text`.

To make it work, go in `Tools` → `Modify Keyboard Shortcuts` → Look for `Yank`→ delete the conflicting assignment that uses `CTRL+Y`. Make sure that `Redo` has that instead.

Kudos to this question that highlighted there could be a hidden conflict, specifically with this "Yank" thing.

Comment: This is the real solution here.

Comment: wonder how rstudio devs ended up thinking that breaking cross application and os conventions was a good idea, back then and in 1.2.5001